# Unable to assign a class member pointer variable

Tags: c++

So I'm just playing around and created a simple class:

```
class C {
public:
    C() {
    }
    void assign() {
        *a = 10;
    }
    int * get() {
        return a;
    }
private:
    int *a;
};
```

Then I create an instance of the class as follows:

```
    C c{};
    c.assign();
```

For some reason, the method assign doesn't actually get called.

```
std::cout << c.get() << std::endl;
```

This returns nothing in the console.

Comment: It should print the address of the variable. Please provide the [mcve].

Comment: @anastaciu for some reason it is not working at all. I just pasted the whole code into an online cpp compiler and it works fine. So now I'm wondering if it's something wrong with IDE (I'm using QT creator)

Comment: do note that dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your pointer is uninitilazied.

Comment: @Tim, I missed it, in fact your pointer is uninitialized, there is already an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing an undefined behaviour by derefercing unallocated memory , You should add this to your class

```
C()
{
 a=new int;
}
```

and

```
~C()
{
    delete a;
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplet because it fails to include the rule of 3/5/0. `C` would be a defective class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is your are derefrencing the unintialized pointer varibale. To accomplished the same you have to initialize your `a` pointer variable.  You can acoomplish the same with this code.

```
class C {
public:
    C() :a(new int){
    }
    void assign() {
        *a =10;
    }
    int* get() {
        return a;
    }
    ~C() {
        delete a;
    }
private:
    int* a;
};
```

Comment: calling `assign` multiple times would result in a memory leak

Comment: This answer is incomplet because it fails to include the rule of 3/5/0. `C` would be a defective class.